# Syncing web service calls across processes

Tags: android, service, semaphore

I would like to have my app's web service calls synchronized so only 1 is executing at any given moment.

I've created an object called WebService, which takes the data needing to be sent (request), sends it to the web service, gets the response and kicks it back out to whatever code invoked the WebService object.

I've added a Semaphore with a count of 1 (ie: mutex) member variable to the WebService object.  This member variable is a static.  It gets locked before the send and unlocked after the send.

Unfortunately, it's not working quite right.  Most of my code will boot up an IntentService and make the web service call.  Some other web services happen in AsyncTasks in the app's process.  I think, because these are two separate processes (?), the static mutex does not extend across the two (?).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can sync my web service calls when some happen in the app's process and some happen in a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some other web services happen in AsyncTasks in the app's process. I think, because these are two separate processes (?), the static mutex does not extend across the two (?)."

Unless you are forcing them to be in separate processes (bad), they will be in the same process.

> Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can sync my web service calls when some happen in the app's process and some happen in a service?

Simple: have them all be handled by the service. Instead of using `AsyncTask`, just have the activities call `startActivity()` on your `IntentService`, with extras and such to pass any necessary data over. Since `IntentService` uses a single thread for processing incoming `Intents`, you will not even need the `Semaphore`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Most of my web service calls do happen in the IntentService, but a few happen in AsyncTasks.  These are usually used to get some data to display on a particular screen that can be discarded.  Also, these AsyncTasks are launched by screens that don't read/write to a database.  The data is passed in and used when the Activity is started.  I'm not quite sure how to get the data from the IntentService to the Activity without using a BroadcastReceiver, which won't work if a new Activity launches and the BroadcastReceiver is unregistered before the web service is finished.

Comment: @Andrew: Then why do you need synchronization of the Web service calls?

Comment: Also, I'm not programmatically creating a separate process, but am I correct in assuming the static semaphore of my WebService object is not extending over all AsyncTasks and the IntentService?

Comment: You could simply "synchronized" the part you need to synchronized. You do not have to implement the "mutex" yourself. It is ok to have two threads calling servicing at the same time?

Comment: @Andrew: "but am I correct in assuming the static semaphore of my WebService object is not extending over all AsyncTasks and the IntentService?" -- if they are all running at the same time, they will be in the same process by default and have access to the same static data members.

Comment: @Dongshengcn I've declared the method that makes the WebService call synchronized, but my problem persists.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then I don't understand how my issue is happening.  The web service I'm hitting takes a token that rolls over every time you make a web service call.  This is why they need to be synchronized.  I've wrapped a mutex around code that retrieves the user's token from the app's database, makes the call, and updates database with the new token.  On occasion I'll receive a token error, telling me my token is bad, which implies that the next web service call is using a stale token before it is updated in the database.

Comment: Ah, I've found the problem.  My mutex was working correctly.  The problem is the timeout.  If a query takes too long to return, the Http object gives up.  Even though I had the timeout set to 10,000 milliseconds, it was still timing out occasionally.